# Images not displayed properly when scrolled iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app i am having `tableview` with sections.The issue is with images. When the user scrolls the list the images displayed are not proper.I know the issue is because of the recycling but still i cannot find any solution.

Code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let myeventCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyEventsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyEventsTableViewCell

        myeventCell.wedImage.clipsToBounds=true;

        myeventCell.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section;

       //to download image
        if wedImgDownload[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == false

        {

//            myeventCell.wedImage.image = UIImage(data: self.webImgData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]);

            if let url = NSURL(string: wedImageUrl[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as String) {

                let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {

                    (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if let imageData = data as NSData? {

                        if myeventCell.tag == indexPath.row+indexPath.section {

                            self.wedImgDownload[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

                            self.wedImgDownload[indexPath.section].insert(true, atIndex: indexPath.row)

                            self.webImgData[indexPath.section].insert(data!, atIndex: indexPath.row)



                            myeventCell.wedImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        else{

            if self.webImgData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] != ""{

                  if myeventCell.tag == indexPath.row+indexPath.section {

                myeventCell.wedImage.image = UIImage(data: self.webImgData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])

                  }

            }



        }



        return myeventCell;

    }
```

Please lemme know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `NSURLConnection`? Can't you use `NSURLSession` or something open source like Alamofire?

Comment: No i dont wanna use library

Answer (score 0):

It's because the cells are being reused. The cells are kicking off requests each time they are reused. The order in which the requests finish can't be determined since they are asynchronous. Once a request does finish and the image is set, the cell gets reused and shows the previous image while the current request is in progress.

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated, you should be using `NSURLSession`. You will need to cache these images instead of kicking off a request each time they are displayed. You will also need to clear the image each time a cell is reused so it doesn't show the previous image when displayed.

There are many open source libraries available which do exactly these things and are extremely well tested and used by millions of users. It would be foolish to not take advantage of them unless it is a hard requirement of the project.

https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage